# Changing src with a button

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, embed

I have a youtube iframe. With name selection.

**HTML :**

```
<div class="video"> 
    <iframe width="420" height="315" name="selection"
    src="" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<a onclick="changeMusic()" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span> Next Song&nbsp; </a>
```

When I click the button I want to increment a integer in javascript so that src of the iframe change with the array index.

**JS :**

```
list[0] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/mQ1huZuZVNA"
list[1] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/qZH5aY48BP8"

var max = 1;
var min = 0;
var x =  0;

//Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

document.getElementsByName("selection").src = list[x]; 

function changeMusic() {    

    if(x<max){
        x = 1;
        document.getElementsByName("selection").src = list[x]; 
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
        document.getElementsByName("selection").src = list[x];
    }

}
```

When the page first loads I want to show the first index as list[0] so that plays the youtube link in iframe. whenever some one clicks a button changes the array index 0 to 1 or 1 to 0 so that the video link changes.

But it doesnt even load the first link from the array.

Comment: `getElementsByName` ? Syntax error..

Comment: @Rayon Dabre I used this site http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Comment: But you have used `getElementByName` not `getElementsByName`

Comment: @Rayon Dabre ty for showing me but it is not the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code work fine after 2 changes.

1. You have to declare your array `list` :

   ```
   var list = [];
   ```
2. You have to select the first element returned by `getElementsByName()` because it'll return all the elements by the name `selection` :

   ```
   document.getElementsByName("selection")[0].src = list[x];
   ```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
var list = [];

list[0] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/mQ1huZuZVNA"
list[1] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/qZH5aY48BP8"

var max = 1;
var min = 0;
var x =  0;

document.getElementsByName("selection")[0].src = list[x]; 

changeMusic = function () {    

 if(x<max){
 x = 1;
 document.getElementsByName("selection")[0].src = list[x]; 
 }
 else{
 x = 0;
 document.getElementsByName("selection")[0].src = list[x];
 }

}
```

```html
<div class="video"> 
    <iframe width="420" height="315" name="selection"
    src="" 
    frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<a onclick="changeMusic()" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span> Next Song&nbsp; </a>
```

Comment: man thanks it works on snippet but not in my pc. It doesnt even load the video, I copied and pasted the same code

Comment: Also I tried in empty script it works but it doest work in  my code

Comment: Please check if there's any error message in browser console.

Comment: Mate I copied part byt part my old code to my new script to see where is the mistake... You know what? Same code worked in the new script but not in the old one....

Comment: can you also up vote my question so that I can get higher rank in stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

> Define `list` as `array`: `var list = [];`
>
> There is syntax error as correct syntax is `getElementsByName` not `getElementByName`. The `getElementsByName()` method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified name

```js
var list = [];
list[0] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/mQ1huZuZVNA";
list[1] = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/qZH5aY48BP8";
var max = 1;
var min = 0;
var x = 0;
var selectionElem = document.getElementsByName("selection")[0];
selectionElem.src = list[x];
function changeMusic() {
 if (x < max) {
  x = 1;
  selectionElem.src = list[x];
 }
 else {
  x = 0;
  selectionElem.src = list[x];
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="video">
  <iframe width="420" height="315" name="selection" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<a onclick="changeMusic()" href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span> Next Song&nbsp; </a>
```

Comment: I defined the array but still nothing changed also I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the first element of the collection returned by `getElementsByName`

```
document.getElementsByName("selection")[0].src = list[x]
```

It always returns a list of nodes (since there can be more elements with the same name)

Comment: well, the code works as evidenced here (http://jsfiddle.net/Lq4boaao/) so youve missed something

Comment: man I am clicking the next song but it doesnt change in your link